# use existing model as a NSManageObject to use Core Data

Tags: iphone, object, core-data, swift3, ios10

i'm new to Core Data and i have built a lot of model like this format:

```
class Song: Mappable {
   var id: String!
   var title: String!
   var album: Album!
}
```

and now i would like to add Core Data functionality to add favorite song, but when i see many Core Data documentation, i see this format:

```
public class Favorite: NSManagedObject {
  @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Favorite> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Favorite>(entityName: "Favorite");
  }

  @NSManaged public var song: String?    
}
```

I can't extend my Song class to NSManagedObject because it conflict with my Mappable (from AlamofireObjectMapper), and i can't create new Song class extend from NSManagedObject.

What should i do ? should i add entity like Favorite, and how to make my NSManagedObject to have model attribute like this

```
@NSManaged public var song: Song?
```

Comment: For just 3 properties I would resign the object mapper and make `Song` an entity (`NSManagedObject` subclass). And don't misuse IUO declared properties as an alibi not to write an initializer.

Comment: 3 properties are the sample, the real code has around 10 properties, all of my Alamofire used AlamofireObjectMapper, so it would cost a lot of work if i remove the object mapper, maybe i must make one exact same model for NsManagedObject subclass with a different name ?

Comment: In about a minute of looking at the project's page I found this: https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper/issues/68#issuecomment-105831195

Comment: i have tried this solution, but it looks like it doesn't work on my project, it always get crashed when i mapping my model from AlamoFire.
Maybe the best solution is make the same model with different name and extends from NSManagedObject